# how to verify data integrity using SHA2?

Tags: java, data-integrity, sha2

```
package abc.xyz;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException; 
import java.security.MessageDigest; 
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException; 

public class SHA2{ 

    private static String convertToHex(byte[] data) { 
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
            int halfbyte = (data[i] >>> 4) & 0x0F;
            int two_halfs = 0;
            do { 
                if ((0 <= halfbyte) && (halfbyte <= 9)) 
                    buf.append((char) ('0' + halfbyte));
                else 
                    buf.append((char) ('a' + (halfbyte - 10)));
                halfbyte = data[i] & 0x0F;
            } while(two_halfs++ < 1);
        } 
        return buf.toString();
    }      
public static String SHA2(String text) 
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException  { 

        MessageDigest mesd;
        mesd = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-2");
        byte[] sha2hash = new byte[40];
        mesd.update(text.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), 0, text.length());
        sha2hash = mesd.digest();//error
        return convertToHex(sha2hash);
    } }
```

I am getting error in implementing digest();

Comment: Please fix the compilation errors, at least! The method you posted doesn't compile for several reasons.

Comment: Also: learn to read the exception you get (and to relay it in your question when it doesn't help you). The exception tells you what the problem is.

Comment: @Joachim there is an error saying "The method digest in the type MessageDigest is not applicable for arguments"

Comment: I'd personally recommend that you use UTF-16BE for the character encoding, as this will work properly with non-ascii characters. It essentially breaks each character down to two bytes and avoids adding any further bytes which other encodings do as a way of meta data. Also, I'd recommend that you look at the loop I've provided for creating the hex string, as this simplifies on the method you've provided in your question (see answer below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SHA-2 isn't an algorithm itself. Wikipedia:

> SHA-2 is a set of cryptographic hash functions (SHA-224, SHA-256, SHA-384, SHA-512)

I think all but SHA-224 should be available.

```
public static String SHA2(String text) 
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException  { 

  MessageDigest mesd = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
  byte[] bytes = text.getBytes("iso-8859-1");
  mesd.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
  byte[] sha2hash = mesd.digest();
  return convertToHex(sha2hash);
}
```

Additionally, the byte array you create isn't necessary. The `digest()` method returns an array itself. The assignment operator never writes a result into an existing array. Unless you specify an index of course.

One more thing. I wouldn't use text.length() when calling `update(..)` as it's not necessarily the same as the length of the resulting byte array. This is mainly the case for multibyte character encoding like UTF-8. It might also occur for characters that can't be mapped, depending on your strategy of choice. Well, the main point is though: you don't need to know what I'm talking about. Simply use an array's `.length` instead to be save :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify which [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) variant you'd like to use: SHA-256 or SHA-512. Use those as the digest names.

Comment: hey I am still not able to implement digest(); can there be a problem with jdk?

Comment: Unless the `MessageDigest` class you use is something other than [`java.security.MessageDigest`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) I can't really see how you'd get an error there. Please double- and tripple-check that the code you compile is actually the code you posted (especially since you posted uncompilable code previously).

Comment: Also: You're still not able to **call** `digest()`. You're not trying to *implement* it here. "Implement" means: to write the code that gets executed when you call it.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already I'd recommend reading the [SUN docs on JCA](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/index.html), particularly the [MessageDigest](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#MessageDigest). If you look at the default [SUN providers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SUNProvider), you'll notice that SHA-2 doesn't actually exist, perhaps try 'SHA-512' instead.

Try:

```
String message = "Some Message";

MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");

messageDigest.update(message.getBytes("UTF-16BE"));
byte[] digest = messageDigest.digest();

StringBuffer digestInHex = new StringBuffer();

for (int i = 0, l = digest.length; i < l; i++) {
    // Preserve the bit representation when casting to integer.
    int intRep = digest[i] & 0xFF;
    // Add leading zero if value is less than 0x10.
    if (intRep < 0x10)  digestInHex.append('\u0030');
    // Convert value to hex.
    digestInHex.append(Integer.toHexString(intRep));
}

System.out.println(digestInHex.toString());
```

Comment: I'd personally recommend that you use UTF-16BE for the character encoding, as this will work properly with non-ascii characters. It essentially breaks each character down to two bytes and avoids adding any further bytes which other encodings do as a way of meta data. Also, I'd recommend that you look at the loop I've provided for creating the hex string, as this simplifies on the method you've provided in your question.

Answer (score 1):

What error? "sha1hash cannot be resolved"? You missed to declare the variable. Pressing ctrl-1 in eclipse does the job. What about sha2hash? I'd say, there should be only one such variable. What about text and textstring? Another self-confusion?

Btw., there's no such thing as "the SHA-2". It's a family of functions, containing e.g., SHA-256. So try something like this:

```
public static byte[] sha2(String text) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    final MessageDigest mesd = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    mesd.update(text.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), 0, text.length());
    return mesd.digest();
}
```